# Connection timed out On Class Extend

Tags: php, model-view-controller, controller

I am fairly new to PHP so I am sure I am doing something wrong, but my code is very simple and I can not seem to see what is causing the timeout error.

### index.php

```
include_once ("./inc/controller/controller.php");
$controller = new controller();
$controller->index();
```

### controller.php

```
include_once('./inc/class/class.common.php');

    class controller {
        public function __construct(){
            $this->common = new Common; // This Line Causes the Error
            echo "Everything Loaded"; // This only executes when above line is gone
        }
        public function index(){
            die("done");    
        }
    }
```

### class.common.php

```
class Common extends controller{
   // I don't even have code in here yet
}
```

Looking at my logs I see the error

```
Class 'controller' not found in /inc/class/class.common.php
```

Why would it not be able to find the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you extend a class and do not define a constructor, it will be inherited from the parent class. So when you create the instance of Common inside controller, it will itself try to create an instance of Common. Then THAT instance will try to create one too, and so on, in an infinite loop.

You can simply override the constructor inside Common. An empty one will do:

```
class Common extends controller{
   public function __construct() {
   }
}
```

But it is odd to want a separate instance of an object that you are already extending.

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer. Can you please explain this sentence "But it is odd to want a separate instance of an object that you are already extending." Thanks.

Comment: The point of extending a class is that your new class will inherit all of the functions and variables from it, and typically build upon them. By extending a class, you are essentially already creating an instance of it, so there is usually no need to duplicate everything again.

Comment: So you are saying if I just want to have common functions like get ip address etc. I should just have a common class and not an extension of one?

Comment: Yes. Although for that particular example, I would also use static methods. Then you don't need to instantiate objects all over the place in order to use the functions. See here for more info http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php